# how to use mysql with less and -F

Tags: mysql, less

I want to use less as a pager for mysql client. I want to add -F to force quit for short outputs. But I can't combine both correctly.

```
root@jupiter:/# mysql -p -u root -h localhost --pager=less -F
mysql: unknown option '-F'
```

is there a way?

Anyway I have some newbie trouble with less:

```
cat oo.txt            # shows me some short garbage
cat oo.txt |less -F   # nothing happens,    I expect show and quit.
less -F oo.txt        # nothing happens,    I expect show and quit.
less oo.txt           # shows the short garbage and waits for q keystroke (or whatever)
```

I am connected via putty if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to quote:

```
mysql -p -u root -h localhost --pager='less -F'
```

`-F` gets passed to `mysql` instead of `less` when you don't pass `less -F` as a single string.

Comment: fine, that is the way!!!, put inside quotes! remains to me a correct flag to show & exit for small stuff

Comment: @LuisSiquot try: `less -F --no-init` (suggestion from http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107315/70524).

Answer (score 1):

From [`man less`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/less.1.html):

```
   -F or --quit-if-one-screen
          Causes less to automatically exit if the entire file can be
displayed on the first screen.
```

So, `less -F file.txt` will make `less` exit automatically **without showing anything**, if the content of `file.txt` can be displayed on the first screen.

Here is a test:

```
$ cat test.txt 
Hello WORLD!
Hallo world!

$ less -F test.txt 
$
```

** See [muru's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/609746/216503) for the other mistake you have made.

Comment: the point is can `less` show & exit?  other flag? what is -F useful for? thanks for your help

Comment: You want a `cat`-like behavior in those cases?

Comment: yes, cat-like for short stuff

Comment: Then like muru already said, you need to use `-X` or `--no-init` i.e. `less -FX file.txt`